# Robber's language in python error

Tags: python

I am a beginning in Python.

I have a function that checks if it is a vowel.

```
def vowel(x):
if(x=='a' or x=='e' or x=='i' or x=='o' or x=='u'):
    return True;
else:
    return False;
```

And a function that tries to convert the string to a robber's language by using the vowel function above. (The algorithm for conversion is to double every consonant and place an "o" in between).

```
def robber(text):
    s=""
    for i,c in enumerate(text):
       if vowel(c)==False:
           s=s.join([c,'o',c])
    return s;
```

When I try to run it by passing robber("asdf") into the function, I get a blank line and "Process finished with exit code 0"

I suspect that there might be multiple errors, but the program is syntactically correct. Could you help me with this?

Comment: That behavior is correct. You seem to be expecting an output printed. Why?

Comment: Here's how you do a vowel check in Python: `def vowel(x): return x in "aouie"`

Comment: suspicious line: `s=s.join([c,'o',c])`

Comment: @DYZ If you do want it as a function, you could also use `vowel = 'aeiou'.__contains__`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I would never recommend anyone to use symbols that start and end with double underscores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **append** to `s` instead of **assigning** and **also appending** the `c` in case it is no vowel:

```
def robber(text):
    s=""
    for i,c in enumerate(text):
        if vowel(c)==False:
            s += ''.join([c,'o',c])
        else:
            s += c
    return s
```

Furthermore some additional remarks:

- it is more *Pythonic* to use `not` instead of `== False`;
- you do not need to use `enumerate(..)` since `i` is never used;
- you do not need to `return True` and `return False` if the test succeeds/fails, simply return the condition; and
- you can rewrite both the `vowel(..)` and `robber(..)` function more elegantly.

So putting it together:

```
def vowel(x):
    return x.lower() in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

and:

```
def robber(text):
    return ''.join([c if vowel(c) else ''.join((c,'o',c)) for c in text])
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I think we saw the error at the same time.

Comment: `'o'.join([c,c])` is even shorter :-)

Comment: `c+'o'+c` is even more efficient.

Comment: what's more efficient is pre-creating the list comprehension instead of passing the generator to `join`

Comment: Don't forget about capital letters `def vowel(x): return x.lower() in ...`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yes I will update the answer. It is however a strange thing in Python that creating a list is more efficient since you expect it to take more memory and construction time for the list.

Comment: join creates the list if it isn't passed the list (needs to have the size for the string object). So it's better to create and pass it beforehand.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yeah I know, but the behavior is similar to `min` and `max` for instance, where one could simply iterate the iterable until it is exhausted and thus reduce the amount of memory since you never need to have all elements in memory at the same time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But strings are real (c-)arrays so if you process them one-by-one you need to realloc your string a lot of times (`O(n**2)` runtime). That's why join creates the list because then you can calculate the final string length before you start joining, resulting in `O(n)` runtime behaviour (however with a higher constant, especially if it's not a sequence already).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid all those append/overwrite errors (and get a much better performance/avoid string concatenation), better start writing those using list comprehension:

```
text = "asdf"

new_text = "".join([c if c in "aeiou" else "{0}o{0}".format(c) for c in text])

print(new_text)
```

result:

```
asosdodfof
```

the new text is a joined list (creates a string) of a list comprehension built using a ternary expression: leave the letter alone if vowel, else create the pattern.

Comment: I think it's a bit of an overkill (not for the case, but for the fact that the writer is a beginner - list comprehension is a bit complex subject for newbies)

Comment: @YotamSalmon maybe, but when you're used to it, it's faster to rewrite a dodgy code with listcomp rather than trying to understand why flow control is broken. I've had my share of debugging beginners code. Now I try to show how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

### Firstly, your problem

On the line `s=s.join([c,'o',c])`, you are actually **replacing** the contents of `s` every time. I think what you do want to do is to **append** it to `s`, so I would use `s += "".join([c, 'o', c])`

Also the use of `join` is wrong - the string before the join comes between every two elements in the given list, not before the first.

So, as I said, the correct form to do that should be:

```
s += "".join([c, 'o', c])
```

**Disclaimer** : Not tested.

### Code readability

As you stated that you are a beginner, let me give you some tips about your coding style (Python's coding style is very unique).

## 1

Instead of doing `x=='a' or x=='e' or x=='i' or x=='o' or x=='u'`, you do:

```
`if x in 'aeiou':`
```

Much more understandable and reads better.

## 2

Doing:
    if ...:
        return True
    else
        Return False

Is very clumsy. Try:

```
return ...
```

And in your case:

```
return x in 'aeiuo'
```

The condition is already a boolean value (`True` or `False`) - no need to reevaluate it ;)